# How do I plot data on a graph vertically using openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

The documentation for openpyxl shows how to plot data horizontally. I'm trying to plot series of data vertically on my graph as shown in the photo.

[image]

```
        chart = LineChart()
        chart.title = "Temperature by city (China)"
        chart.style = 13
        chart.y_axis.title = 'Mean Temperature'
        chart.x_axis.title = 'Year'

        cities = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_col=1, max_row=ws.max_row)
        years = Reference(ws, min_col=3, min_row=2, max_col=3, max_row=ws.max_row)
        temps = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_col=2, max_row=ws.max_row)

        chart.add_data(cities, titles_from_data=False)
        chart.add_data(years, titles_from_data=False)
        chart.add_data(temps, titles_from_data=False)

        chart.set_categories(years)

        stacked = deepcopy(chart)
        stacked.grouping = "stacked"
        stacked.title = "Temperature by city (China)"
        ws.add_chart(stacked)
```

I need the series on the right side to be the cities (Changchun, Peking, etc, etc) somehow - and vertical axis shows the average temps, horizontal axis shows a line for each city.

For example:

[image]

But the 'batches' would be the city names in my case. 'Size' would be average temperature, and 'Test Number' would be the years.

Comment: You might want to include a screenshot of the chart you want but it sounds to me like you have series for cities and with the years being the category.

Comment: @CharlieClark The series should be the different cities. There are about 10 or 12 cities.

Comment: Then the dates are your categories. Each series of temperatures should be headed by the name of the city. I would suggest A2... for the dates, B1 for Changchun, C1 for the next city, etc. See http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/charts/line.html#id1

Comment: @CharlieClark Updated the question to make it clearer

Comment: So, what you want to do is already covered in the documentation.